# Can I use the Transaction attribute in the `AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory` implementation?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-transactions, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, transactionmanager

I am building a service using Spring WebFlux, R2dbc, and Jasync. As I am considering various databases in the current service, I want to use different `ConnectionFactory` for each package.

So, I tried to create an `AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory` implementation and branch it from `determineCurrentLookupKey` method to a different `ConnectionFactory` with the package name. Like this.

```java
public class CustomRoutingConnectionFactory extends AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory {
    @Override
    protected Mono<Object> determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager.forCurrentTransaction()
                                                .map(this::getR2dbcKeyByPackage);
    }
    
    private String getR2dbcKeyByPackage(TransactionSynchronizationManager transactionManager) {
        if (transactionManager.getCurrentTransactionName()
                              .contains(SomeR2dbcProperties.BASE_PACKAGE)) {
            return SomeR2dbcProperties.KEY;
        } else if (transactionManager.getCurrentTransactionName()
                                     .contains(OtherR2dbcProperties.BASE_PACKAGE)) {
            return OtherR2dbcProperties.KEY;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("not supported package: %s");
    }
  
  ...
}
```

I tried to compare the package name with the method name used for Transactional annotation in Transaction attribute (definition).

I didn't know for sure about this, but I thought I could use the information here because I could access the `TransactionContext` using the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`.

By the way, there is no information about Transaction like the picture below. The picture below shows the part that I checked after running the method with Transactional annotation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHhP9.png)

`TransactionDefinition` is used in the `doBegin` method of `R2dbcTransactionManager`, so is there any way to use it in the `determineCurrentLookupKey` method?